# Prove the language $\{x \in \Sigma^* : \exists w \in \Sigma^* \ xww \in L \}$ for regular language $L$ is regular

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

> Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ and $L$ be a regular language. Prove that
> $$Z(L) = \{x \in \Sigma^* : \exists w \in \Sigma^* \ xww \in L \}$$
> is a regular language.

I tried to build a NFA based on the DFA that accepts $L$ but failed to do so. I don't know how to ensure the $\, ww \,$ part. Please advise.

Comment: Related: the language $\{ w \mid ww\in L\}$ is sometimes called the root of $L$. The root of a regular language is again regular. See [If  L  is a regular language then so is  √L={w:ww∈L}](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41281/4287)

Comment: @HendrikJan I don't see how this helps (though it looks close). Any hint?

Comment: My aim was to indicate that the $ww$ suffixes can be recognized using a finite state construction. Nathaniel made that explicit in his answer. In the $\sqrt L$ construction you keep $w$, in Nathaniels construction it is omitted from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = (Q, \delta, q_0, F)$ a DFA that accepts $L$. For $q, q' \in Q$, define:

- $L_{q,q'} = \{u\in \Sigma^*, \delta^*(q, u) = q'\}$;
- $L_{q',F} = \{u\in \Sigma^*, \delta^*(q', u) \in F\}$.

It is quite easy (can you prove it?) to see that those languages are regular.

Now the language $\{x\in \Sigma^*\mid \exists w\in\Sigma^*, xww\in L\}$ can be written as:
$$\bigcup\limits_{q\in Q}L_{q_0,q}\cdot M(q)$$
Where $M(q) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}\emptyset&\text{if }\bigcup\limits_{q'\in Q}L_{q,q'}\cap L_{q',F}=\emptyset\\\{\varepsilon\}&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$

$M(q)$ is regular since it is either $\emptyset$ or $\{\varepsilon\}$, so that means that $Z(L)$ is regular.

Comment: Thank you @Nathaniel, can you please explain the intuition behind $M(q)$? I'm trying to understand what it means. I can't see why the original language can be expressed in that way.

Comment: We want to find the states $q$ such that there is a "double" path to a final state of $A$, that is states $q$ such that $\exists w\in \Sigma^*, \delta^*(q, ww)\in F$. Those $w$ are expressed by $\bigcup\limits_{q'\in Q}L_{q,q'}\cap L_{q',F}$, so we just need to now if this set is empty or not, and that is what is expressed by $M(q)$.

Comment: Thank you. If this set is empty, shouldn't we accept only  $x \in L$? In this case the union would accept any path from $q_0$ to $q$, wouldn't it?

Comment: If $M(q) = \emptyset$, that means that $q$ is not a good state to end with when reading $x$. In this case, $L_{q_0,q}\cdot M(q) = \emptyset$ (because the concatenation with the empty set is the empty set), so those paths are not considered.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the concatenation with the empty set if the empty set. Now it's clear, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The operator $Z(L) = \{ x \mid xww\in L \text{ for some } w\}$ takes strings from the original language $L$ but keeps only prefixes $x$ that are obtained by chopping a suffix of the form $ww$.

This is a special application of the right quotient operation: $L/K = \{ x \mid xy\in L \text{ for some } y\in K\}$.

It is known that the family of regular languages is closed under right quotient of *arbitrary* languages, see [Show L1 /L2 is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55578/4287). For your problem take $K = \{ww\mid w\in \Sigma^*\}$.

Comment: Thank you, that's a neat solution :)